# How to override regular expression within the range of strings that satisfies another regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to find regular expression for double quoted string.For that I have simply put the following expression

```
\".*\"
```

But the problem is if some strings that match with another regular expression come within double quotes the above expression will not match with it.

For eg: If we want to give particular color for double quoted string that also contains strings (for eg: keyword or number, providing different color for keywords and numbers) that matches with another regular expression will not give the expected result.ie, **if a keyword or number appears within double quotes it will take the color of keyword or number itself instead of taking color of double quoted string**.How can I resolve this?Is there any way to override regular expression within another expression?

Comment: try this non-greedy regex `\".*?\"`

Comment: Same problem persists on this regex

Comment: could you provide an example alng with expected output?

Comment: Avinash Raj's regex is fine. What 'exactly' are you trying to do?

Comment: regex for double quoted string \".*\",regex for number "[-+]?\\b\\d+\\b",set different colors for strings that matches above expressions.Everything works fine if input is like this: "aaa", 22, If input is "aaa 22" ,aaa will be in the color of double quoted string and 22 will be in the color of number

Comment: You need to post another `clear` question. This one is ambiguous.

Comment: @Adhi, Maybe, you could post your whole implementation to make your question clear. From my understanding, you firstly find some double-quoted-string from one input string, and then set one color to it. Next, you will find number-regex from the same input string, and then color it. Then your problem happened as you described. If so, you could change the order of setting color. FYI.

Answer (score 0):

```
"[^"]+"|\d+
```

Try your regex this way.Put `""` quote regex the first with other regexes after it piped along.This way `""` will be consumed first and rest of the regex will not apply over it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/2